# Настройка Nginx после смены домена

Tags: nginx

Есть такой конфиг:

```
server {
server_name site.com www.site.com;
charset off;
index index.php index.html;
disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/vhosts-resources/site.com/*.conf;
access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/site.com.access.log;
error_log /var/www/httpd-logs/site.com.error.log notice;
ssi on;
set $root_path /var/www/name/data/www/site.com;
root $root_path;
location / {
    location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
        try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
    }
    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf)$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback;
    }
    location / {
        try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
    }
}
location @fallback {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080 /;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    access_log off;
}
listen 11.111.11.11:80;
```

}

```
server {
server_name site.com www.site.com;
ssl_certificate "/var/www/httpd-cert/name/name.crt";
ssl_certificate_key "/var/www/httpd-cert/name/name.key";
ssl_ciphers EECDH:+AES256:-3DES:RSA+AES:!NULL:!RC4;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;";
ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam4096.pem;
charset off;
index index.php index.html;
disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/vhosts-resources/site.com/*.conf;
access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/site.com.access.log;
error_log /var/www/httpd-logs/site.com.error.log notice;
ssi on;
set $root_path /var/www/golden/data/www/site.com;
root $root_path;
location / {
    location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
        try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
    }
    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf)$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback;
    }
    location / {
        try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
    }
}
location @fallback {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080 /;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    access_log off;
}
listen 11.111.11.11:443 ssl;
```

}

Я изменил домен с site.COM на site.RU. Выставил редирект:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://site.ru/$1 permanent;
```

С site.com на site.ru редиректит, только вот и site.ru редиректит на самого себя. Получаеться циклиеский редирект.
Помогите это исправить.

Answer (score 1):

```
server {
    listen 11.111.11.11:80

    server_name site.com www.site.com;
    return 301 https://www.site.ru$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name site.ru www.site.ru;
    charset off;
    index index.php index.html; 
    # всё остальное, редирект не нужен
    # ...
}
```

Comment: Не помогло.  Совсем удалил файл конфига и все равно идет редирект. В чем моет быть проблема?

Comment: Единственный возможный вариант это то что в самом приложении (PHP) прописан базовый адрес site.com и PHP редиректит на него. Измените базовый адрес в приложении на правильный (site.ru)